# cannot create backbone js collection from server json response

Tags: json, backbone.js, laravel-5

OK. 
I know many questions have been asked here for this problem but my question is a bit difference from it.

I have laravel as the back end server and a defined route:

Route::post('/allusers',array('uses'=>'UsersController@index');

@index method (laravel):

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $user=DB::table('users')->select('id','name','email')->get();;
    if($user){
        return response()->json($user);
    }
    return "failed";
}
```

and then, I have a backbonejs collection and model like bellow: 
user model:

```
user = Backbone.Model.extend({
urlRoot: '/user/'+this.id,
    default:{
        'name':'',
        'email':'unknown@no-name.com',
    },
render:function(){
    console.log(this.name);
}
, initialize:function(){
    console.log('model user created'+this.cid);
    console.log(this.name);
}
```

});

and backbone collection:

```
UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:user,
    url:'/allusers/',
    parse:function(resp,xhr){
             rt= _.toArray(resp);
 return rt;
    },
    initialize:function(){
       this.fetch();
    }
});
```

but the colletion cannot be create. the `models` attribute of collection is always 0.

here is the JSON response from laravel :

```
[Object { id=1,  name="abc",  email="someone@google.com"}, Object { id=2,  name="anotheruser",  email="anotheruser@gmail.com"}]
```

Please, any suggestion.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the valid `JSON` from your laravel. Backbone assumes it is wrong and triggers error callback.use this snippet to return as `JSON`.

```
if($user){
      return Response::json($user->toArray());
    }
```

With perfect json returned you don't have to parse in model. so you can remove the parse function from your model (unless you want to manipulate on data).

So your model should look like this,

```
UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:user,
    url:'/allusers/',
    initialize:function(){
       this.fetch();
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't use `fetch`without an error callback, since this will debugging and error handling hell when something goes wrong.

Comment: Just tried to keep answer simple and straight to the question, thanks for the comment though